# CVS: get time and date when file was tagged

Tags: cvs

I am using CVS. I checked in a file, then later tagged it. Is there any way to get the date when it was tagged? I tried running cvs log and I found the date when it was checked in, but not when it was tagged.

Answer (score 1):

The only suggestions I can make involve you having enabled history logging or setting up something to use `taginfo`. Maybe not of help to you but could be for someone else browsing the same problem or pre-empting it.

*If* you have the history logging enabled (existence of the `CVSROOT/history` file means it's enabled) you might be able to try using the following:

`cvs history -a -T`

This will show you the tagging that has occurred. However since this command it parsing a file it's O(n) with respect to the size of the repository history (i.e. number of files and activities). So it can get a bit slow. You can find out more here: http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#History%20--%20A%20Summary%20Of%20Repository%20Activity

If you think you can do better then you can add a hook into the `CVSROOT/taginfo` file. Here you can log your tagging activities however you like. Take a look here for more info: http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#The%20taginfo%20File